# Take and debounce usage issue

Tags: rx-java

I have the next test case

```
public void testLimitAndPublishSubject() throws InterruptedException {
    PublishSubject<Boolean> mBooleanPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    mBooleanPublishSubject.asObservable()
            .doOnEach(__ -> System.out.println("on value emitted "+System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .take(1)
            .doOnEach(__ -> System.out.println("on value emitted 2 "+System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnEach(__ -> System.out.println("on value emitted 3 "+System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .subscribe(__ -> System.out.println("done "+System.currentTimeMillis()));
    mBooleanPublishSubject.onNext(true);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    mBooleanPublishSubject.onNext(true);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

and the output is

```
on value emitted 1454063289770
on value emitted 2 1454063289770
on value emitted 2 1454063289779
on value emitted 3 1454063289780
done 1454063289780
on value emitted 3 1454063289780
```

I can't figure out why the `on value emitted 2` and `on value emitted 3` appears in the log twice and why the debounce delay doesn't work. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Discussed [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3656)

To resolve duplicate items in log issue i should to use `doOnNext` instead of `doOnEach`, such as doOnEach include `onCompleted` events

`take(1)` completes observable immediately, that is why debounce doesn't work. The delay should be used instead of

```
mBooleanPublishSubject.asObservable()
        .doOnNext(__ -> System.out.println("on value emitted " + System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .take(1)
        .doOnNext(__ -> System.out.println("on value emitted 2 " + System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .doOnNext(__ -> System.out.println("on value emitted 3 " + System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .subscribe(__ -> System.out.println("done " + System.currentTimeMillis()));
```